# How to update Access token from YouTube API v3.0

Tags: android, youtube-api, http-post, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

In my android app I use Youtube API for liking video. I make POST Request to get **access token** and **refresh token**, but I understand that this token will live only one hour.
So I want to update access token using my refresh token. I read YouTube API docs and see how this POST Request looks like, but don't know how it make in code.

```
    private class updateToken extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?"
                +"client_id={CLIENT_ID}&"+
                "client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&"+
                "refresh_token={REFRESH_TOKEN}"+
                "&grant_type=refresh_token");
        //Don't know, I need Bearer or not
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody;
        try {
            responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("responseBody: " + responseBody);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
        return null;
    }
}
```

another my variant:

```
private class refreshToken2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
        httppost.addHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {AccessToken}");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refresh_token", {RefreshToken});
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "{Myclient_id}");
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "myclient_secret"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "refresh_token"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(result);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Get Error:

```
"error": "unauthorized_client","error_description": "Unauthorized"
```

i have all parameters for this request, but don't know to do it, always see different errors, please help me.

[image]

Comment: It seems like a simple POST request to the API. What's the issue? Please update the question with the code you are using to update the access token.